# CSS div box z-index

Tags: html, css

I have created a website where I have used a box shadow to put a shadow on the main-div box

```
box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
```

The problem is that you cannot specify where the shadow should appear other than offsetting its location.

What this means is that I cannot have 2 shadows running down either side of the box without also having a shadow at the top or the bottom of the box at the same time! (at least not to my reckoning)

What I thought I could do is position another box "overlay-div" at the bottom of my "main-div" box , give it a white background and overlay it over the shadow that I want to hide...

My problem is that the "overlay-div" not only overlays the box I want to hide, it also overlays the following div and covers part of the content.

Is there any way to have an overlay, overlay a specific box but not another???

I've tried z-index but it doesn't work.  I really want to have no shadow on the bottom portion of the #content-footer div and have it smooth into the white background.

Here is my code:

```
<style>
#content-footer {
 float: left;
 width: 980px;
 height: 250px;
 padding: 30px 30px 0;
 background: #EBEBEB;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(#EBEBEB 20%, white 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(20%, #EBEBEB), color-stop(100%, white));
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
#sitemap {
 background-color: white;
 height: 300px;
 float: left;
 width: 920px;
 margin: -130px 30px 0 30px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
</style>

<div id="content-footer">
    ... content ... 
</div>

<div id="sitemap">
   ... sitemap ...
</div>
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5456769/gradeint-box-shadow.png)

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful if you could jsfiddle.net your problem.

Comment: If jsfiddle.net were working right now... I haven't been able to connect to the site for the last 10 minutes :-)

Comment: Yeah me either, I think it's down...jsbin is a nice alternative

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your post correctly, you intend to have a shadow on the left, right, and top sides of `#sitemap` and *not* on the and bottom side.

In that case, [here is a jsbin solution](http://jsbin.com/ecexuf/2/edit#html,live).

Your endeavors with `z-index` weren't working because `z-index` only works with elements that have a `fixed`, `relative`, or `absolute` positioning applied on them.

**Crucial Parts:**

- `#sitemap` has `position:relative`
- `#content-footer` is nested within `#sitemap` and has `position:absolute`, `height:280px`, and `bottom: -280px`
- `#sitemap` and `#content-footer` have the same width

I recommend using [this tool](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) for configuring a customized, ultra-compatible gradient.

Answer (score 0):

try using :after or :before pseudo selectors. 
you can also you gradient with transparent background on one end and #fff on another.

```
    #content-footer {
 float: left;
 width: 980px;
 height: 250px;
 padding: 30px 30px 0;
 background: #EBEBEB;
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(#EBEBEB 20%, white 100%);
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(20%, #EBEBEB), color-stop(100%, white));
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
position:relative;
}

#content-footer:after {
position: absolute;
content: "";
background-color: white;
 height: 300px;
 width: 920px;
 margin: -130px 30px 0 30px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a simple fix for it,
just place the content-footer in a div with overflow hidden and same height as such

```
#content-footer-container {
  overflow:hidden;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 280px; //+30px considering padding
}
```

as simple as that.
Any shadow to top and bottom will be cropped off and shadow to side will be visible as width is larger than footer div.

Comment: That's a good results but not perfect - it also cuts the shadow off the top... not the desired result but pretty close to it...

Comment: just give the content-footer div a "margin-top:-5px". The inner div will slide under it to give the desired result.